# Bike site and links

Tags: modification

Links to sites with a new or unique design is what I am looking for.
Post the site with most links for bike related information.

Comment: The site with the most links is http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

In the world of Recumbents and Velomobiles, you can try:

Mike's Recumbent Links: http://www.mikebentley.com/bike/bents/

Dutch collection of World-wide Velomobile/Recumbent links: http://dutchbikes.nl/velomobile-diy-kit/velomobile-links/

or a historical persepctive: http://www.icebike.org/30-iconic-velomobile-designs-from-the-past-85-years/

..and just in case I am doing your homework for you, you can get better information by Googling 'new designs in cycling' and find all sorts of goodies!  :-)

Comment: We try not to answer questions that are going to end up closed/deleted.  Remember SE is about practical solutions to real world problems on bikes,  not "do my design homework for me"

Comment: Considering that you only put the topic 'on hold' 8 hours ago and I answered 23 hours ago, it is quite possible that I do not have the requisite powers *to see into the future* or read the mind of the moderator to determine the best course of action :P.  The poster asked, and I provided a potential answer as a practical solution.  The links provided have already been around for several years.  Plus we have this thing called a search engine to find any updated or outmoded links (the net remembers everything).  And let us not forget the Wayback machine website.  :-)

Comment: Additionally, the poster may not be familiar with the best keywords for Googling his query, nor be aware of certain fields of cycling, such as Velomobiles and recumbents.  I have adjusted my answer accordingly.  :)

Comment: No criticism intended - this is a good answer to a bad question.